# removing interlopers from a legal numbered pattern

Tags: python, algorithm, pattern-matching

I have a list of numbers that follow the [legal numbering](http://www.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~keith/Word/exercises/exercise4/exercise5/files/stacks_image_55-legal-numbering.jpg) scheme

The list looks like this -

```
['1', '1', '1.1', '1.2', '1.3', '1.4', '1.5', '2', '1.6', '2', '2.1', '2.2', '2.3', '2.4', '3', '2.5', '3', '3.1', '3.2', '4', '5', '4', '6', '6.1', '6.2', '9333', '6.3', '6.4', '5', '6.5', '6.6', '6.7', '6.8', '6.9', '6.10', '6', '7']
```

There are however ***'integer'*** interlopers (numbers that are not consistent with the scheme) in this list. For instance the first '1' at the top of the list, the '2' that comes before '1.6'. Is there a known algorithm or pattern for identifying inconsistent numbers and removing them from the list?

**EDIT**: Since the question isn't clear to some, I've posted what a legal numbered scheme looks like:

```
['1','1.1','1.2','1.3','2','2.1','3','3.1','3.2'....]
```

Note however that I can't compare this against a static list because this is just a numbering scheme. '2' could be followed by '2.1' and then back to '3' or could be followed by '2.1','2.2' and then back to '3'.

Comment: What is the list is `['1.1', '2.1', '1.2']`? Is the invalid value the `2.1` or the `1.2`? How do you decide between them?

Comment: Since you've linked to a Computer Science department website, with "exercises" in the URL, am I right in assuming that this is a homework assignment for you? If so, please show what you have tried. Doing students' homework outright for them is generally frowned on here.

Comment: the same way you can say the *second* 1 and the *1.6* are the offending ones. The question is not clear.

Comment: @MarkByers The legal numbering scheme is a numbering scheme lawyers use in contracts and is available in the MS word's numbering drop down (this question is not ms word related though). 2.1 is the invalid value because '2' must precede '2.1' according to the numbering scheme.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Please don't be patronizing. The link just shows you what the numbering scheme looks like. I might as well have posted [this link] (https://www.google.com/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=2&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=legal+numbering). Does that mean I work with google? Why don't you try helping out?

Comment: @tokland Actually the question is clear. Just that the answer isn't. 1.6 isn't offending - I've stated the objective and identified the offending items, which clearly shows what pattern I'm trying to obtain.

Comment: @MarkByers My apologies. I should clarify that the interlopers would typically be integers (i.e. without a dot). Yes, typically both would be considered legal. However, the problem I'm describing involves removing numbers that 'appear' to be consistent with the scheme but aren't. the first '1' is a real problem because there's no way of distinguishing either value (and I'll probably use external data (this is an information extraction problem) to determine which initial value to select. But with the scenario you described, 2 precedes a valid dot number and hence 2 is the interloper.

Comment: @MarkByers no they don't work, but the sorted-set (the alternative solution) gives me a list I can work against. still checking it out - no solution in sight yet.

Comment: Many students come here expecting their work to be done for them; there's no patronization involved in clarifying that you're looking for a complete solution rather than pointers or guidance.

Comment: "no solution in sight yet": That's hardly surprising. Your requirements are very vague. How are we supposed to use "the interlopers would typically be integers"? What does "typically" mean? Always? 90% of the time? 50% of the time? And how are we supposed to use this information to decide which numbers are illegal? Can you show what the expected result should be if the input is `1 2 2.1 1.1  1.2 1.3 4 1.4 2 3 4`? Please show many more examples of what you're trying to do and how various edge cases should be handled.

Comment: @MarkByers I'll handle the edge cases if you actually have a solution for the typical cases i.e where the interlopers are integers.

Comment: @VivekDurai: If you had originally written that the invalid terms will **ALWAYS** be integers then I'd have posted an answer within a few minutes of you posting your question. But I know *exactly* what will happen... you'll say "Yes thank you for this answer... it works perfectly for integers, but **sorry** I forgot to mention but there is another case it really needs to handle, can you update your answer to do this too?" And of course it will require an entire rewrite and a totally different algorithm. tl;dr **Make your requirements CLEAR if you want good answers!**

Comment: @JoshCaswell Understood. Any solution to this question is likely only a pointer for me. I've tried to isolate one part of a larger problem and present it as a question that has an algorithmic solution.

Comment: @MarkByers Your road rage is commendable. You also seem to be prescient. I've edited the question accordingly. Do you have an answer now?

Answer (score 4):

```
for a,b in zip(mylist, mylist[1:]):
    if a==b:
        print('Value {} is repeated'.format(a))
    elif a > b:
        print('Either {} or {} is out of order'.format(a,b))
```

On your data, this gives

```
Value 1 is repeated
Either 2 or 1.6 is out of order
Either 3 or 2.5 is out of order
Either 5 or 4 is out of order
Either 9333 or 6.3 is out of order
Either 6.4 or 5 is out of order
Either 6.9 or 6.10 is out of order
Either 6.10 or 6 is out of order
```

alternatively,

```
mylist = sorted(set(mylist))
```

automatically gets rid of duplicates and puts everything in order.

**Edit:** Mark Byers makes a good point about 6.9 / 6.10 not sorting right; the only solution I see to that is to parse the string so we are comparing integers, like so:

```
mylist = sorted(set(mylist), key=lambda s:map(int, s.split('.')))
```

results in

```
['1', '1.1', '1.2', '1.3', '1.4', '1.5', '1.6', '2', '2.1', '2.2', '2.3', '2.4', '2.5', '3', '3.1', '3.2', '4', '5', '6', '6.1', '6.2', '6.3', '6.4', '6.5', '6.6', '6.7', '6.8', '6.9', '6.10', '7', '9333']
```

Comment: Nice. I can actually uniquify and sort the list and compare that against the existing list. Thanks.

Comment: sorted(set(['1','1.1','2','1.2','2','2.1','3','3.1','3.2','4.2','3.3','3.4'])) gives ['1', '1.1', '1.2', '2', '2.1', '3', '3.1', '3.2', '3.3', '3.4', '4.2']. So that actually seems to work for sorting...just that I need to work out how to use this to remove the offending ones.

Comment: @MarkByers I'm referring to the alternative solution not the first one he posted. And I clarified that this is not a complete solution. You have a problem when others post leads instead of complete solutions?

Comment: @MarkByers You seem to have some trouble (A) reading (B) actually providing solutions. This is posted as a comment to the alternative solution (read: "alternatively,..."). Why waste your time and my time trolling around if you don't actually know how to solve this?

Comment: @MarkByers I've clarified forever and ever that the offending numbers are only integers. Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 2):

You basically want to compare it against a sorted version of the list

```
for a, b in zip(numbers, sorted(numbers, key=lambda x: x.split('.'))):
    if a != b:
       print('error at ' + a)
       # or do something else
```

Comment: Thanks. I've added a clarification that the offending numbers can only be integers. If numbers  = ['1','1.1','2','1.2','2','3','3.1','3.2','4.2','3.3','3.4'], it should spit errors at the first '2' and at '4.2'.

Comment: Sorry. If numbers  = ['1','1.1','2','1.2','2','3','3.1','3.2','4','3.3','3.4'], it should spit errors at the first '2' and at '4'.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def get_next_dotted_term(s, i):
    for x in s[i + 1:]:
        if '.' in x:
            return int(x.partition('.')[0])

def make_valid(s):
    result = []
    current = 0

    for i, x in enumerate(s):
        if '.' in x:
            result.append(x)
        else:
            ix = int(x)
            nextdot = get_next_dotted_term(s, i)
            if current + 1 == ix and (ix <= nextdot or not nextdot):
                result.append(x)
                current += 1
            else:
                print "Error: " + x
    return result

print make_valid(['1','1.1','2','1.2','2','3','3.1','3.2','4','3.3','3.4'])
```

Result:

```
Error: 2
Error: 4
['1', '1.1', '1.2', '2', '3', '3.1', '3.2', '3.3', '3.4']
```